# How to pass an repeating object to an user control into repeater

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, datarepeater

For example I use telerik rad grid, and bind list of users to it

```
rgUsers.DataSource = GetUsersList();
rgUsers.DataBind();
```

I have user control **UserEditor** that receives User object,

```
<radG:RadGrid runat="server" ID="rgUsers">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
          <radG:GridTemplateColumn>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
              <EditItemTemplate>
                <uc:UserEditor ID="UserEditor" runat="server" User='???????' />
              </EditItemTemplate>
          </radG:GridTemplateColumn>
          ...
```

Can I pass an User object to the **UserEditor**, or I must to make it in Data Binding event?

Comment: You need to do it in your (I don't know for radGrid) RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it works like native ASP.NET controls:

[RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation - Event sequence](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-event-sequence.html)

```
<radG:RadGrid runat="server" ID="rgUsers" OnItemDataBound="rgUsers_ItemDataBound">  

protected void rgUsers_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.EditItem) 
    {
        User user = (User)e.Item.GridDataItem;
        UserEditor userEditor = (UserEditor )e.Item.FindControl("UserEditor");
        UserEditor.User = user;
    }

}
```